# How to leave frame-focus mode in Vimperator

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I accidentally pressed <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> on GitHub and it shows only the frame created by the [Octotree extension](https://github.com/buunguyen/octotree).

However, if I open the browser in private mode, it shows the full page. I know I could just kill the session and open Firefox again, but this has happened a few times and it's pretty annoying.

I don't have any related configuration in my `.vimperatorrc` file.

How do I disable this mode?

Comment: How did you get into this ? I can't reproduce: on github, open octotree, press `;f`: it highlights the main frame and I have no pb continuing.